# Configure build process in CMake's ExternalProject_Add

Tags: cmake

I have a C++ project (Superproject) that depends on another project I have no control over (Subproject). To be able to build my project I need to build first the Subproject and then the Superproject, that links to the Subproject built libraries.

Both projects use CMake to configure the corresponding Makefiles. Manually I would have to download the Subproject into a subfolder of the Superproject (`externals/Subproject`) and then `cd` into `externals/Subproject/build` and run `cmake ..` and then `make target1`.

I would like to automate this process from within the Superproject CMakeLists file using ExternalProject_Add functionality. So far I have something like

```
ExternalProject_Add(Subproject
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals"
    GIT_REPOSITORY "git@path/to/repo/Subproject.git"
    GIT_TAG "master"
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build"
)
```

which correctly downloads and builds the `all` target of the Subproject. But when I try to modify it so that it only builds the `target1` of the Subproject with

```
ExternalProject_Add(Subproject
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals"
    GIT_REPOSITORY "git@path/to/repo/Subproject.git"
    GIT_TAG "master"
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build"
    BUILD_COMMAND "${MAKE} target1"
)
```

it fails at executing the `make` command complaining that `/bin/sh` does not know what `target1` is.

How can I modify the compilation target from `ExternalProject_Add` to suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it by removing the quotes in the `BUILD_COMMAND` statement, changing curly braces to parenthesis around the `MAKE` directive, and then disabling the `INSTALL_COMMAND`:

```
ExternalProject_Add(Subproject
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals"
    GIT_REPOSITORY "git@path/to/repo/Subproject.git"
    GIT_TAG "master"
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build"
    BUILD_COMMAND $(MAKE) target1
    INSTALL_COMMAND "")
```